# Why does FastAPI execute the Pydantic constructor twice when returning from the route function?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have a use case where I want to create some values inside my class on the construction of the model.  However, when I return the class to FastAPI for converting to JSON when I call the API, the constructor gets run again and I can get differing values from my original instance.

Here is a contrived example to illustrate:

```py
class SomeModel(BaseModel):
    public_value: str
    secret_value: Optional[str]

    def __init__(self, **data):
        super().__init__(**data)
        # this could also be done with default_factory
        self.secret_value = randint(1, 5)


def some_function() -> SomeModel:
    something = SomeModel(public_value="hello")
    print(something)
    return something


@app.get("/test", response_model=SomeModel)
async def exec_test():
    something = some_function()
    print(something)
    return something
```

The console output is:

```sh
public_value='hello' secret_value=1
public_value='hello' secret_value=1
```

But the JSON in the web API is:

```json
{
  "public_value": "hello",
  "secret_value": 2
}
```

When I step through the code I can see the `__init__` being called twice.

First on the construction `something = SomeModel(public_value="hello")`.

Second, which is unexpected to me, is in the API handler `exec_test` on the `return something` call.

If this is the wrong method to set up some internal data within the class please let me know the correct method to use. Otherwise, this seems like this is unintended behavior of one of the modules.

Answer (score 9):

This is supposedly expected behavior when you use `response_model`. It is not quite explained clearly in the docs, but in the [Response Model](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/#response-model) section, it says that:

> FastAPI will use this `response_model` to:
>
> - Convert the output data to its type declaration.
> - Validate the data.
>   ...

When you `return something` at the end of your route function `exec_test`, FastAPI will convert that to *another* `SomeModel` instance, do validation, and then return that validated instance. So, you get a different instance than the one you originally returned.

I've had this same issue before: [Why does the response_model seem to `__init__` the same object twice?](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2359), which led to this old issue: [[BUG] Double validation pydantic model when used response_model](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/3021). Most of the responses are along the lines of "it's expected":

> This is something expected and the point of the `ResponseModel`, it ensures your data is in the correct order.

> It's not exactly duplicated. Internally it validates once (if you add a `response_model`), but on your endpoint function you're manually validating once again.
>
> I believe the answer would be: it's the expected result.

The solution I've since learned is to ***never*** mutate the models on `__init__` like that. The [answer provided by alex_noname](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69099754/2745495) using `Field` or validators are, I also think, the best approaches to avoid this issue.

Here are the other workarounds if you *really* need that mutation on `__init__`:

1. Just skip validation on the route function

   In `some_function`, where you are instantiating `SomeModel`, that will *already* raise validation errors if the arguments are wrong (ex. `public_value={'a': 1})`. Repeating the validation with `response_model` could be redundant. There was even a [PR on FastAPI to skip validation on `response_model`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/pull/1434) but that never got merged.

   You can just remove `response_model`, and replace it with [`responses`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/additional-responses/#additional-response-with-model) to maintain the documentation with OpenAPI.

   ```
   # @app.get("/test", response_model=SomeModel)
   @app.get("/test", responses={200: {"model": SomeModel}})
   async def exec_test():
       something = some_function()
       print(something)
       return something
   ```
2. Let `some_function` return the raw values of your model, rather than an instance of the model itself. Basically, moving/delaying the instantation and validation of your model onto the route function.

   ```
   def some_function() -> dict:
       # something = SomeModel(public_value="hello")
       something = {"public_value": "hello"}
       print(something)
       return something

   @app.get("/test", response_model=SomeModel)
   async def exec_test():
       something = some_function()
       print(something)
       return something
   ```

   As the docs says, FastAPI will convert the return value to the `response_model` type, thereby instantiating the model. Doing it here means validation will happen very late. Also, you'll have to deal with losing the convenience of using Pydantic models everywhere.
3. Related to #2, have 2 separate models, 1 for internal use and 1 for putting into the `response_model`. This is similar to having separate [input and output models](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/?h=output#add-an-output-model) example from the FastAPI docs:

   ```
   class InternalModel(BaseModel):
       public_value: str

   class OutputModel(BaseModel):
       public_value: str
       secret_value: Optional[str]

       def __init__(self, **data):
           super().__init__(**data)
           self.secret_value = randint(1, 5)

   def some_function() -> InternalModel:
       something = InternalModel(public_value="hello")
       print(something)
       return something

   @app.get("/test", response_model=OutputModel)
   async def exec_test():
       something = some_function()
       print(something)
       return something
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using [`response_model`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/) for path operation, your return value is validated against it. But since you are returning an already validated instance of the model, this happens twice. It wouldn't be noticeable if you didn't use a mutating `__init__` method that can generate different values for every instantiation of the model regardless of the input values.

I think the most preferable solution is to use the [`default_factory`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#field-with-dynamic-default-value) function, since in this case the dynamic values ​​will be generated only at the time of instantiation of objects in your code, and the ready-made value will be used in the process of model validation while returning.

```
class SomeModel(BaseModel):
    public_value: str
    secret_value: int = Field(default_factory=lambda: randint(1, 5))
```

If for some reason you do not want to use the approach above, then you can use an [always validator](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#validate-always), that will allow you to check that the value is passed or it needs to be created:

```
class SomeModel(BaseModel):
    public_value: str
    secret_value: int = None

    @validator('secret_value', pre=True, always=True)
    def secret_validator(cls, v):
        return randint(1, 5) if v is None else v
```